# Logout Sound for XMonad

Tags: haskell, archlinux, xorg, window-managers, xmonad

I am using XMonad on Arch Linux, and my lack of experience in Haskell is finally getting in the way of configuring my system.

So, I wanted to have a Session login and logout sound. I use `.xinitrc` to start xmonad, where I can easily add a sound to act as my login sound. For logout, xmonad quits from the logged in session and drops right back to a tty which is logged out.

For this, my plan is to have a key-binding, which when pressed, will play a sound file and show a confirmation prompt to quit. As soon as the user responds, the session will quit.

My key-binding is like this right now

```hs
("C-q", confirmPrompt def "exit" $ io (exitWith ExitSuccess))
```

This can perform the exit command as intended, but I cannot find a way to execute a spawn command just before it.

I tried `("C-q", spawn "mpv --no-video ~/my-sound-file.oga" && confirmPrompt def "exit" $ io (exitWith ExitSuccess))` but to no avail. It throws an error, which most certainly is not according to Haskell syntax.

If anyone can do multiple commands like this on a single key-binding, or, execute a script when xorg closes, please let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
spawn "mpv foo.oga" >> confirmPrompt def "exit" (io (exitWith ExitSuccess))
```

The two changes of interest are `&&` -> `>>` and `$` -> parentheses.

Comment: Wow...that worked!! I appreciate..man.. 

Would it be possible to explain how logical and `&&`, redirection operator `>>`, `$` , `->` and <+> differ in Haskell in comparison to other programming languages? 

Just when I thought I was starting to understand Haskell, these operators seem to mean entirely different from what I knew .

Comment: Logical and works exactly the same in Haskell as in other languages. I'm honestly not sure why you tried it here; it's an operation that combines two logic values and neither of the arguments you gave it are logic-like values. `>>` is not redirection in Haskell; it is a kind of sequencing operation. `a >> b` means first do `a`, then do `b`... though admittedly for a somewhat restricted collection of `a`s and `b`s, specifically monadic actions. In xmonad, when you see a type like `X ()` or `X Bool` or similar, those are monadic actions.